CryptoJS - decrypt PBEWithHMACSHA512AndAES_256
I'd like to decrypt strings encrypted with algorithm PBEWithHMACSHA512AndAES_256 using CryptoJS.
Encrypted strings are meant for a Java Spring Jasypt application and are created in this way:
    var passphrase = "XxxXXXXxX";
    var saltWA = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
    var ivWA = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
    var iterations = 1000;
    var plaintext = "some text";

    var keyWA = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, saltWA, {keySize: 256/32, iterations: iterations, hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA512});

    //ENCRYPT
    var ciphertextCP = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, keyWA, {iv: ivWA});
    var ciphertextHex = ciphertextCP.ciphertext.toString(); 

    // Concatenate
    var encryptedData = saltWA.clone().concat(ivWA).concat(ciphertextCP.ciphertext);  //     Concatenate on binary level
    var encryptedDataB64 = encryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);  

This works but you have to pass the ciphertext used during encryption
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertextCP, keyWA, {iv: ivWA});
    var decryptedString = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

I would like to have a different function in order to get plain content from an encrypted string. Unfortunately this doesn't work
   var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: 
   CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedDataB64)}, passphrase);

Encrypted data example: PvQalMekYBNW2Kl5QWSjZNGgycJ2Ato+ISx7L1i2IA9BaCzwEPq55FbSq71U6gT5
any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

First of all, it makes no sense to hex decode (CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse()) obviously Base64 encoded data (encryptedDataB64). Furthermore, it's not entirely clear what you are actually looking for. The concatenation of salt, IV and ciphertext is a custom format that isn't known to the CryptoJS library, which is why CryptoJS doesn't include a ready-made functionality for a compatible decryption logic. You can implement a formatter and a KDF with this logic and pack it into a cfg. You can then use the syntax CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(<encrypted data>, <passphrase>, cfg) if that's what you want.
